# Python 2to3 - do not remove unicode prefixes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3, unicode-literals

I am converting a legacy codebase to python3 and do some dry runs of 2to3. 2to3 removes the `u''` prefix from unicode literals creating a lot of noise in the diffs. Is there a way to disable this (as `u'my string'` is valid py3 syntax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help:

```
2to3 --help
...
  -x NOFIX, --nofix=NOFIX
                        Prevent a transformation from being run
  -l, --list-fixes      List available transformations
...
```

With `--list-fixes`, we find the transformation to ignore, `unicode`.

Result: `2to3 --nofix=unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html, you can exclude certain set of fixers by `-x` option.

Perhaps the following would do what you want.

```
2to3 -x unicode example.py
```